# What are the Type Parameters for F# Events and Handlers?

Tags: .net, events, f#, handler, type-parameter

I'm trying to use .NET Events and Handlers using the example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx

Specifically, the Creating Custom Events section. But I'm trying to define it in an interface, so the property would be abstract. In abstract properties, generic type parameters are not allowed, so I can't do something like this:

```
abstract member evt : Event<_>
```

I haven't been able to find a good example of what should actually go in the `_`. There is one further down on the same page, but it's unclear how I can apply that to my custom event. Can anyone help, or link me to a resource that clearly explains how to define the type parameters for both `Event<_>` and `Handler<_>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type parameter that matches the containing type's type parameter:

```
type IMy<'a> =
    abstract member evt : Event<'a>
```